# Track open connections/requests with httpClient in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

How can I track if there are still open connections/requests when using HttpClient?
I want to display for example a Loading Indicator Widget when there are still open connections.

Comment: Track open connections using code? If yes, are you using 1 instance of `HttpClient` for multiple requests or 1 `HttpClient` 1 request?

Comment: I rather want to use one instance for multiple requests. But I can do both.

Comment: I use the "Dio" package, and you can use the "Interceptors", check out this article https://medium.com/flutter-community/dio-interceptors-in-flutter-17be4214f363

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use interceptor or any third-party libraries, there are some approaches you can try. 
One such simple approach would be to create your own custom Class that embeds HttpClient and then you can provide similar functionality.
You can then use same instance of that Class every where.
The provided example keeps track of the total open request and it's not full code but an idea how to proceed by starting with get request.
**Update:**
As suggested by [Ali Yar Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9138027/ali-yar-khan), I have updated the code with singleton pattern.

```
class CustomHttpClass {
   int _totalOpenRequest = 0;

   int get totalOpenRequest => _totalOpenRequest;

   final _httpClient = HttpClient();

   static final CustomHttpClass _singleton = CustomHttpClass._internal();

   factory CustomHttpClass() {
     return _singleton;
   }

   CustomHttpClass._internal();

   Future<HttpClientRequest> get(String host, int port, String path)  async{
     ++_totalOpenRequest;
     try {
       final httpClientRequest = await _httpClient.get(host, port, path);
       return httpClientRequest;
     } catch (e) {
        print("inside catch");
        throw(e);
     } finally {
       print(_totalOpenRequest);
       --_totalOpenRequest;
       print("inside finally");
       print(_totalOpenRequest);
     }
   }

  // closing won't allow further calls and will throw error
 // make sure to call only before destroying/quitting your app
  void close({bool force = false}) {
    _httpClient.close(force: force);
  }

}
// Using any instance of CustomHttpClass will always refer to single instance of this class.
```

Comment: a singleton pattern would be much good than this

Comment: I have updated it to singleton pattern. Thanks for suggestion :). @AliYarKhan

Answer (score -1):

The Flutter DevTools has a nice feature that it hosts a webServer so you can debug everything of your application on your browser or any IDE that supports it.

So, if you're on VSCode and your already installed your Dart/Flutter plugins, you will need to start your application on Debug mode, press F1 and search for `devtools` and select `Flutter: Open DevTools`.

[image: Print screen of search bar on VSCode with devtools options]

Then you can open the general DevTools screen, or any Monitoring feature that it provides to you. I really like to open the DevTools in the WebBroser on this last option:

[image: Devtools options on execute bar VSCode]

Even this tool is really cool, sometimes it cannot monitor correctly all the network calls for some reason. So if you're using some lib to deal with your HTTP requests, you can find some logger lib such as pretty_dio_logger that was one of I've already used.

Comment: Sorry this is not the answer I was looking for. I want to track the open connections in code so I can display for example a Loading Indicator Widget.

Comment: So you want a way to identify a state that some request isn't complete yet to show or hide a Loading Widget? To this you'll need to search about State management. I usually use Bloc + Cubit to call the Remote Data Sources (make requests) and, when a request is made, I set a state of loading to show/hide data/loading widget.

Bloc/Cubit is only one way to do that. There's a lot made by community.

Answer (score -1):

First, you must understand what state management?
We have some state management: [Flutter document](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)
After understand about state management, you can define state for your features. We can define 3 basic state: loading, loadedSuccess, error.
With each state, we display other widget.
A here: with loading state, we will return Loading Widget or Loading Popup,
loadedSuccess state will return UI with data. in case error with network or developer, we will return error ui default.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to track open connections/requests with httpClient in Flutter without using a third-party package, you can use the http package's default http.Client class and manually keep track of the open connections. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
class HttpClientManager {
  static http.Client _client = http.Client();
  static int _numConnections = 0;

  static http.Client get client => _client;
  static int get numConnections => _numConnections;

  static Future<http.Response> get(String url) async {
    _numConnections++;
    try {
      final response = await _client.get(Uri.parse(url));
      return response;
    } finally {
      _numConnections--;
    }
  }

  static void close() {
    _client.close();
  }
}
```

You can utilize this manager class like below

```
final response = await HttpClientManager.get('https://api.example.com');

print('Number of open connections: ${HttpClientManager.numConnections}');
```

Make sure to handle error cases appropriately and call `HttpClientManager.close()` when you're done making requests to ensure proper cleanup.